# angularjs order by to object with space

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angularjs-orderby

I've a list of users that contains object with spaces like this;

> 'User Name, First Name, Last Name, Phone #, User Image'

while binding this list to datatable, I'm doing this to achieve my data

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in lstUsers | orderBy : ['User Name']>

   <td> <img ngf-thumbnail="user['User Image']" alt="" id="imgUserImage{{$index}}" /></td>
   <td>{{ user['User Name'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ user['First Name'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ user['Last Name'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ user['Phone #'] }}</td>                        
</tr>
```

it works perfectly fine except the `order by`, it gives error if I use it in this way `orderBy : ['User Name']`

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Name' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [User Name] starting at [Name].

and if I use `orderBy : '[User Name]'` , it throws this error;

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Name' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 7 of the expression [[User Name]] starting at [Name]].

and if I use `orderBy : 'User Name'` , it throws this error;

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Name' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [User Name] starting at [Name].

and if I use it without space like this `orderBy : 'UserName'` , it doesn't give any error but not apply any order to table.

What should I do to apply order on table? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just surround a field name with **`UTF8 code`** for quotation mark:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in lstUsers  | orderBy:'\u0022User Name\u0022'">
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myController",function($scope){
  
$scope.lstUsers  = [
{"User Name": 'SACHIN', age: 12},
{"User Name": 'AJMAL', age: 14},
{"User Name": 'SMITH', age: 15},
{"User Name": 'RICHARD', age: 16},
{"User Name": 'OSCAR', age: 32}
];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
  
<div ng-repeat="user in lstUsers | orderBy:'\u0022User Name\u0022' ">
   <h1>{{user['User Name']}}</h1>
   <h1>{{user.age}}</h1>
  </div>
 </body>

  </html>
```